# python code to get xml from server and process it's elements

Tags: python, xml, url

I'm trying to get .xml file from a URL http://192.168.1.80/api/current and process the content by SUBSCRIBER by SUBSCRIBER,i wrote code to get a xml file as string using python urllib2 module,i like to convert xml file to object and process,how can i proceed

```
import urllib2
from xml.dom import minidom

usock = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.1.80/api/current')
xmldoc = minidom.parse(usock)
usock.close()
data = xmldoc.toxml()
print data
```

xml content

```
<NSE COMMAND="CURR_USERS_RSP">
    <SUBSCRIBER>
        <SUB_MAC_ADDR>
            70:16:00:C1:12:76
        </SUB_MAC_ADDR>
        <SUB_IP>
            192.168.1.20
        </SUB_IP>
        <LOCATION>
            0
        </LOCATION>
    </SUBSCRIBER>
    <SUBSCRIBER>
        <SUB_MAC_ADDR>
            58:E6:F6:E5:7B:78
        </SUB_MAC_ADDR>
        <SUB_IP>
            192.168.1.21
        </SUB_IP>
        <LOCATION>
            0
        </LOCATION>
    </SUBSCRIBER>
</NSE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i figure it out a way to solving above problem

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib2
from xml.dom import minidom

url = 'http://192.168.1.80/api/current'

try:
    usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(usock)
    usock.close()
    data = xmldoc.toxml()
    root = ET.fromstring(data)

    for ele in root.findall('SUBSCRIBER'):
        print 'MAC = ' + ele.find('SUB_MAC_ADDR').text + ', IP = ' + ele.find('SUB_IP').text + ', Location = ' + ele.find('LOCATION').text

except Exception as e:
    print e.getcode()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the xml file. Do not forget to select the appropriate `xml` parser. See [this](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

Comment: is there a way to do this only by using standard modules comes with python

Comment: Yes, you can use python's [xml library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)